# How to a Disable a Checkbox only in UAT and PROD without getting disabled on Dev and Localhost servers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a checkbox named 'SendDownstream' on all servers i.e, LocalHost,Dev,UAT & PROD. I am trying to disable that checkbox only on UAT & PROD but couldn't get it done. I need the checkbox only on DEV and LocalHost.

I am trying to disable that checkbox only on UAT & PROD but couldn't get it done. When I write disabled in the input line of Index.html, the changes were getting reflected only on Localhost but not showing up on UAT & PROD. I guess changes were to be done only on Index.html and Index.js file's. Here are the both files...

Index.html file

```
<div class="form-group col-8">
                      <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="sendDownstream" disabled >
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="sendDownstream">send Downstream </label>
                      </div>
```

Index.js file

```
function callServer(method, body, callback)
  {
    var errorMessage;
    var headers = sendDownstream.is(':checked') ? {'ui-consumer-name': consumerName,
 'company name-send-downstream': 'true'}: {'ui-consumer-name': consumerName};
```

Any Leads would be helpful.. Thank you !!

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give you a definitive answer with the details you provided, but this issue has to be debugged like any other bug - trace problem layer by layer until you find the root cause.

Start with outermost layer (browser) and work backwards. Some suggestions:

- check in browser dev tools to see if expected html is being sent there
- if not, check the frontend files on the server to see if they contain the expected change and so on.

Comment: I got some leads from my teammates asking how to get environment property in html file and should write a condition it seems... and also, we have base URL's for uat and prod in yml files individually. then Is there any way to get those links as a variable...??